# iOS: geojson iOS access

Tags: ios, json, xcode, geojson

Developing for the iPad, I have created a file that i call Coordinates.geojson. I would like to access it from within a classfile called JsonDecoder.m

Here is JsonDecoder.m

```
@implementation JsonDecoder



- (id)initWithJson
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Coordinates" ofType:@"geojson"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSError *error;
    _json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    return self;
}

- (NSArray*) getCoordinatesFromShelf:(NSString *) bookShelfName
{
    NSArray *coordinates = [[[_json objectForKey:@"shelf1"] objectForKey:@"coordinates"]objectAtIndex:1];
    for(id i in coordinates)
        NSLog(@"%@",i);
    return coordinates;
}
@end
```

And my Coordinates.geojson:

```
{
    "shelf1": {
        "name": "six.png",
        "coordinates": [
                        [
                         14,
                         25,
                         329,
                         138
                         ],
                        [
                         14,
                         185,
                         329,
                         138
                         ],
                        [
                         14,
                         344,
                         158,
                         138
                         ],
                        [
                         185,
                         344,
                         158,
                         138
                         ],
                        [
                         14,
                         94,
                         158,
                         138
                         ],
                        [
                         185,
                         500,
                         158,
                         138
                         ]
                        ]
    }
}
```

How can i retreive these values from within a class file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The above worked perfectly

I had forgot to set target membership to my project for the geojson file.

To do this, mark your jsonfile, click on the fileinspector and toogle the checkbox of your project at "Target Membership"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS >= 5 you can parse it without external libraries

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Coordinates" ofType:@"geojson"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

But the content of the file isn't a valid JSON string.

If possible change it to something like:

```
{
    "shelf1": {
        "name": "six.png",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                14,
                25,
                329,
                138
            ],
            [
                14,
                185,
                329,
                138
            ],
            [
                14,
                344,
                158,
                138
            ],
            [
                185,
                344,
                158,
                138
            ],
            [
                14,
                94,
                158,
                138
            ],
            [
                185,
                500,
                158,
                138
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Then you can access it with:

```
NSDictionary *shelf1 = [json objectForKey:@"shelf1"];

//OR

NSArray *coordinates = [[json objectForKey:@"shelf1"] objectForKey:@"coordinates"];
```

Comment: 2013-04-26 06:51:24.515 skattkistan[1580:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
***